# How to select only years (or months) in WPF DatePicker?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the Datepicker that comes with visual studio 2010 but I can't find an option that lets me select only years, or only months of a given year.

(I see the wpf toolkit calendar supports this, but I'm wondering if maybe the one that comes with visual studio does as well?)

Comment: Then how come you can't just do selectedDate.Month or something to that affect..??

Answer (score 1):

Duh, I should've just used the Calendar control with a popup. (Calendar supports DisplayMode)

Answer (score 0):

will something like this work if you coded it..???

```
DateTime selectedDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
int intMonth = DateTime.Month(selectedDate.Month);
```